# Running Django with gunicorn: Bad Request (400)

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am following this tutorial to set up a Django application and serve it with Gunicorn on a Debian DigitalOcean server: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

I have got as far as the section starting "Now that you have gunicorn, you can test whether it can serve your Django application by running the following command". Now I'm stuck.

In other words, I can successfully run the application using `python manage.py runserver`, but not by using gunicorn.

I've successfully accessed my app with:

```
$ python manage.py runserver xx.xx.xx.xx:8000
```

Now from the same directory, I'm trying to run:

```
$ gunicorn my_django.wsgi:application --bind xx.xx.xx.xx:8001
```

It appears to start OK, but when I go to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8001, I see:

```
Bad Request (400)
```

I'm not sure how to debug this: there's nothing in `/var/log/gunicorn/`.

I have set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['xx.xx.xx.xx']` in my settings file.

UPDATE: Being an idiot: gunicorn was looking in production settings file, not local settings file. Setting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in production settings fixed it.

I'd still really like to know how to debug problems like this though.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for posting your update, and for me taking the time to read the update. Consider posting an answer because I had the same issue. I changed ALLOWED_HOSTS a million times, but never changed my local_settings one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer: gunicorn was looking in production settings file, not local settings file. Setting the ALLOWED_HOSTS in production settings fixed it.